# Linux: get amount of memory swapped in/out over a time period

Tags: linux, memory, monitoring, swap

is there an (easy(?)) way to get the the amount of data moved to/from swap over a certain time ? Maybe, either integrated over all processes and time or integrated over specific processes and time?

Story: I have a machine which tends to swap. However, I do not know, if swap is 'actively' used. I.e., if it is constantly swapping or let's say just the shared libraries not really used are swapped away after some time and 'active' memory usage happens in mem in the end.

Thus, I am looking for a way to comfort myself, that the swap usage *may* be not serious...

Cheers and thanks for ideas,
  Thomas

Comment: If there is a way it is probably inside `/proc/`

Comment: yes, I was thinking about going through /proc as well, but that would probably not catch any short living forks or so. 
Also vmstat shows at least the total paging in/out since boot, so I could take differences between specific times as quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

This can be relatively easily (if you know kernel MM subsystem) done via SystemTap.
You need to know the name of functions which do swapin/swapout, create corresponding probes and two counters incremented from probes. Finally, you need a timer which is fired every N seconds, dumps current counters and resets them.

Answer (score 0):

here is my temporary solution to get the overall number of pages swapped in/out between to calls using vmstat

```
#!/bin/sh
OLDSWAPPEDIN=$SWAPPEDIN
OLDSWAPPEDOUT=$SWAPPEDOUT
PAGEINOUT=$(vmstat -s | grep swapped 2>&1)
SWAPPEDIN=`echo $PAGEINOUT | awk '{print $1}'`
SWAPPEDOUT=`echo $PAGEINOUT | awk '{print $5}'`
SWAPPEDINDIFF=`expr $SWAPPEDIN - $OLDSWAPPEDIN`
SWAPPEDOUTDIFF=`expr $SWAPPEDOUT - $OLDSWAPPEDOUT`
```

I tried to avoid temporary files for storage variables (so either sourcing it or create the variables at login would be necessary)